# Шоу (кого? или чего?) талантов

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, одушевленность

Как правильно задать вопрос: *шоу* (кого?/чего?) *талантов*?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

**ТАЛАНТ**, -м. [греч. tálanton - весы, вес] 1. Выдающаяся врождённая **способность**, особая природная одарённость. 2. **Человек** с такими способностями, дарованием. Молодые таланты.

Скорее всего, речь идет о представлении талантливых людей, поэтому: **шоу (кого?) талантов**.

Но лучше сказать: **шоу (какое?) талантов.**

Answer (score 0):

Формально говоря, оба варианта корректны:

1. Шоу, в котором участвуют (кто?) таланты (талантливые люди). Шоу (кого?) талантов.
2. Шоу, в котором люди демонстрируют свои (что?) таланты.  Шоу (чего?) талантов.

Но в реальном общении так вопрос не ставят, а спрашивают: "Какое это шоу?"

Comment: В реальном общении спрашивают: "Что за шоу?"

Comment: @Сашка-дурак Из нацкорпуса: Меня лично подобные пип-шоу никак не привлекают. ― Что-что? ― переспросил профессор. ― **Какие шоу**?

Comment: Сравните: "Что за комментарий написал  @Сашка-дурак?" и "Какой комментарий написал @Сашка-дурак?"

Comment: - Саня, что за комментарий ты написал?!       - я?.. Какой комментарий? -                    
 Такой диалог возможен?